# How to compare two registered values in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am a noobie in Ansible and struggling with comparing two registered values in my playbook.

I am fetching a list of codes from 2 different hosts and trying to compare them, but fail.

Expectation is that if all values are the same, then will display the message that "The variables are the same", if not then "The variables are different".

Output of values look like this, but I am getting the message that values are not equal.

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "res_green": [
        "CodeListString=01,03,04,05,07,12,13,V2,V7,V8,V9,X1,X2,X3,X4"
    ]
}`

`ok: [remotehost] => {
    "res_blue": [
        "CodeListString=01,03,04,05,07,12,13,V2,V7,V8,V9,X1,X2,X3,X4"
    ]
}
```

```yaml
---
- name: compare remote file to a local reference
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  become: true
  vars:
    local_reference: "{{ local_folder }}server_output_green.txt" 
    remote_files_2_check: "{{ remote_folder }}server-config.properties" 
    res_green: []
    res_blue: []
 
  tasks:
    - name: Check the bad debts results from green side
      shell: grep CodeListString {{ local_reference }}  
      register: result_green
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['localhost'][0]

    - set_fact:
        res_green: "{{ result_green.stdout_lines|list }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['localhost'][0]

    - debug:
        var: res_green
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['localhost'][0]
    
    - name: Check the paymentgateway bad debt codes
      shell: grep CodeListString {{ remote_files_2_check }}  
      register: result_blue
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['remotehost'][0]

    - set_fact:
        res_blue: "{{ result_blue.stdout_lines|list }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['remotehost'][0]

    - debug:
        var: res_blue
      when: inventory_hostname == groups['remotehost'][0]

    - name: Vars are equal
      debug: 
        msg: 'Vars are equal'
      when: res_green == res_blue 
   
    - name: Vars are not equal 
      fail:
        msg: 'The variables are different'
      when: res_green != res_blue
```

Outcome sample:

````json
PLAY [compare remote file to a local reference] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [Check the bad debts results from green side] ********************************************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [remotehost]
    changed: [localhost]
    
    TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost]
    skipping: [remotehost]
    
    TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "res_green": "CodeListString=01,03,04,05,07,12,13,V2,V7,V8,V9,X1,X2,X3,X4"
    }
    skipping: [remotehost]
    
    TASK [Check the paymentgateway bad debt codes] ************************************************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [localhost]
    changed: [remotehost]
    
    TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [localhost]
    ok: [remotehost]
    
    TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [localhost]
    ok: [remotehost] => {
        "res_blue": "CodeListString=01,03,04,05,07,12,13,V2,V7,V8,V9,X1,X2,X3,X4"
    }
    
    TASK [Vars are equal] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    skipping: [localhost]
    skipping: [remotehost]
    
    TASK [Vars are not equal] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "The variables are not equal"
    }
    ok: [remotehost] => {
        "msg": "The variables are not equal"
    }
    
    PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    remotehost : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   
    localhost : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   ```
````

I don't know how to break down the list element by element and compare it with what is found in the other list.

Expectation is that the playbook doesn't fail when values are equal OR fail when the values are not equal.

Comment: Based on your output above, the two variables are equal when I test on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather green_csv
    shell:
      cmd: grep CodeListString green.csv | cut -d '=' -f 2
    register: green_csv

  - name: Generate green_list
    set_fact:
      green_list: "{{ green_csv.stdout | split(',') }}"

  - name: Gather red_csv
    shell:
      cmd: grep CodeListString red.csv | cut -d '=' -f 2
    register: red_csv

  - name: Generate red_list
    set_fact:
      red_list: "{{ red_csv.stdout | split(',') }}"

  - name: Show the difference
    debug:
      msg:
       - "There are {{ difference | length }} different elements."
       - "The elements are: {{ difference }}."
    vars:
      difference: "{{ green_list | difference(red_list) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Gather green_csv] *********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Generate green_list] ******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Gather red_csv] ***********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Generate red_list] ********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the difference] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - There are 0 different elements.
  - 'The elements are: [].'
```

It is possible to make it a lot easier by

- Pre-processing with `grep CodeListString <list>.csv | cut -d '=' -f 2` as it will gather the Comma Separated Values (CSV) only
- Creating a list from via `<list>_csv.stdout | split(',')`
- Just compare the elements via the [difference filter – the difference of one list from another](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html)
- Proceed maybe further with [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)

---

Another approach could be [`fact_diff` module – Find the difference between currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/fact_diff_module.html)

```yaml
  - name: Show the difference in JSON format
    ansible.utils.fact_diff:
      before: "{{ green_list }}"
      after: "{{ red_list }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show the difference in JSON format] **************************************************************************************************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 01
+02
 03
-04
-05
-07
+06
+08
 12
 13
 V2
```

if there is any difference (*annot.: ... and which I've created to show the behavior*).