# Ansible: How to compare 2 host's services with ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-facts

I want to compare 2 Red Hat server's service list by Ansible and print out only the different service that is running.

For instance:

- server 1 running services: `a,b,c,d`
- server 2 running services: `c,d,e,f`

In this case, I only want to print `a,b` services.

Below is my playbook.

```yaml
- hosts: server1:server2
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Run command to get running services on server1
      shell: systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running --no-pager | grep '\.service' | awk '{print $1}'
      register: result_server1
      when: "'server1' in inventory_hostname"

    - name: Run command to get running services on server2
      shell: systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running --no-pager | grep '\.service' | awk '{print $1}'
      register: result_server2
      when: "'server2' in inventory_hostname"

    - name: Set facts for server1 services
      set_fact:
        server1_services: "{{ result_server1.stdout_lines }}"
      when: "'server1' in inventory_hostname"

    - name: Set facts for server2 services
      set_fact:
        server2_services: "{{ result_server2.stdout_lines }}"
      when: "'server2' in inventory_hostname"

    - name: Find the difference between services
      set_fact:
        service_difference: "{{ server1_services | difference(server2_services) }}"
      when: "'server1' in inventory_hostname"

    - name: Print the difference for server2
      debug:
        msg: "Service difference for server1: {{ service_difference }}"
      when: "'server1' in inventory_hostname"
```

The problem is it prints out all of the services for `server1`.

```json
TASK [Print differences] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/custom-playbooks/2getservicelist.yaml:49
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": "Service difference for server1: [u'auditd.service', u'crond.service', u'dbus.service', u'getty@tty1.service', u'httpd.service', u'irqbalance.service', u'lvm2-lvmetad.service', u'NetworkManager.service', u'polkit.service', u'postfix.service', u'rhnsd.service', u'rhsmcertd.service', u'rsyslog.service', u'sshd.service', u'systemd-journald.service', u'systemd-logind.service', u'systemd-udevd.service', u'tuned.service', u'vgauthd.service', u'vmtoolsd.service']"

skipping: [server2] => {}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

[`difference` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html) can't provide me that I assume. How can I solve this?

Comment: Onyl or just do [`service_facts` module – Return service state information as fact data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html) and [`fact_diff` module – Find the difference between currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/fact_diff_module.html) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false


  tasks:

  - name: Gather Service Facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Show all
    debug:
      var: services

  - name: Show difference
    ansible.utils.fact_diff:
      before: "{{ hostvars['test1.example.com'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
      after:  "{{ hostvars['test2.example.com'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

could result into an output in example of

```yaml
changed: [test1.example.com]
--- before
+++ after
@@ -27,11 +27,6 @@
...
-besclient.service:
-    name: besclient.service
-    source: systemd
-    state: running
...
+io.podman.service:
+    name: io.podman.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: inactive
+    status: disabled
...
+node_exporter.service:
+    name: node_exporter.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: running
+    status: enabled
...
```

**Further Readings**

Use Cases for `service_facts` and how to use it

- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [How to pass variable from Ansible `service_facts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [Ansible `service_facts` filtering by partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420765/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to start stopped services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953222/6771046)
- and many more ...

or in general

- [How to compare two registered values in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77278927/6771046)

Comment: Quite an elegant solution, didn't knew about this.

Comment: Works like a charm with 2 servers but when I try to add a loop for multiple IP addresses, it gets weird. Maybe my logic is incorrect. I try to add 'loop' to 'after' section. The play hasn't got any error but it can't find the differences. I will update this post as well regarding to that.

Comment: @G.Baysec, in such case I recommend to add a complete new question with full description where you explain that you like to compare one list of services with another list of service out of many, list of hosts ... Like in your update and as it should gain more input then ...

Comment: That make sense, I will close this question indeed. Tank you for your response